# tikzpicture and array side by side in subfigure won't align

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, subfloats, arrays

I am trying to align side by side a `tikzpicture` (an image of a network) and an array (a matrix) but no matter what I do they wont align properly. Two arrays side by side and two `tikzpicture`s side by side align correctly (on the same line) but when I mix the two I get a problem. I have yet to find a post dealing with these two environments in a subfigure. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12ptm]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.1\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=1.5cm,
        thick,main node/.style={circle,draw,font=\Large\bfseries}]

\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,shape=circle];
\node[draw=none, shape=circle,scale=0.02cm, fill=none] (n1) {} ;
\node[draw,shape=circle,scale=0.02cm, main node](n2) [left of=n1] {$M$} ;
\node[draw,shape=circle,scale=0.02cm, main node] (n4) [above of=n1] {1} ;
\node[draw,shape=circle,scale=0.02cm, main node] (n3) [below of=n1] {3} ;
\node[draw,shape=circle,scale=0.02cm, main node] (n5) [right of=n1] {2} ;

\draw[<->] (n2) to[bend left=30] (n4);
\draw[<->] (n2) to[bend right=30] (n3);
\draw[->] (n4) to[bend left=30] (n5);
\draw[<->] (n3) to (n4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\[
\begin{array}{cccc}
\begin{array}{cccc} 
\\
&A &  &\;B\\
\end{array} 
\\
\begin{array}{cc}
 a \\
\\
  b\\

\end{array} 
\begin{array}{|cc|cc|}
\hline 
$6$&&$2$&\\
&$6$&&$7$\\ \hline
$7$&&$0$&\\
&$2$&&$0$\\ \hline

\end{array}
\end{array}
\]

\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, what you get is the network figure and then the array on what appears to be another line diagonally below (to the right) of the network. I want them just side by side.

Comment: As an aside, see [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Comment: Thank you, an old habit that I never saw the consequences of. Unfortunately, it doesn't fix my problem haha.

Comment: ...but maybe it fixes a bad habit.

Comment: Yes I will no longer use $$, promise :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of spurious `$` and the `subfigure` markup wasn't doing a lot so I deleted it. Here I use `\raisebox` to vertically centre the tikz.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12ptm]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}

\raisebox{-.5\totalheight}{\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=1.5cm,
        thick,main node/.style={circle,draw,font=\Large\bfseries},
align=center]

\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,shape=circle];
\node[draw=none, shape=circle,scale=0.02cm, fill=none] (n1) {} ;
\node[draw,shape=circle,scale=0.02cm, main node](n2) [left of=n1] {$M$} ;
\node[draw,shape=circle,scale=0.02cm, main node] (n4) [above of=n1] {1} ;
\node[draw,shape=circle,scale=0.02cm, main node] (n3) [below of=n1] {3} ;
\node[draw,shape=circle,scale=0.02cm, main node] (n5) [right of=n1] {2} ;

\draw[<->] (n2) to[bend left=30] (n4);
\draw[<->] (n2) to[bend right=30] (n3);
\draw[->] (n4) to[bend left=30] (n5);
\draw[<->] (n3) to (n4);
\end{tikzpicture}}
$\begin{array}{cccc}
\begin{array}{cccc} 
\\
&A &  &\;B\\
\end{array} 
\\
\begin{array}{cc}
 a \\
\\
  b\\
\end{array} 
\begin{array}{|cc|cc|}
\hline 
6&&2&\\
&6&&7\\ \hline
7&&0&\\
&2&&0\\ \hline

\end{array}
\end{array}
$
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks great and was definitely something I was unaware of!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `baseline` style to set the vertical align.
In your case

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(n2)}, ...]
```

should be ok.